# A borrow issue while trying to use std::util::replace

Tags: rust

```
use std::util::replace;
```

Suppose we have these structs:

```
struct Foo {
    a: ~[Baz],
}

struct Bar {
    a: ~[Quux],
}

struct Baz {
    x: bool
}

struct Quux {
    x: bool,
    y: Bar,
}
```

The following works just fine:

```
    let mut foo = Foo{a: ~[Baz {x: true},
                           Baz {x: false}]};

    println!("{}, {}", foo.a[0].x, foo.a[1].x); // true false
    replace(&mut foo.a[0], foo.a[1]);
    println!("{}, {}", foo.a[0].x, foo.a[1].x); // false false
```

This, however, does not work:

```
    let mut bar = Bar{a: ~[Quux {x: true, y: Bar {a: ~[]} },
                           Quux {x: false, y: Bar {a: ~[]} }]
    };

    println!("{}, {}", bar.a[0].x, bar.a[1].x); // true false

    replace(&mut bar.a[0], bar.a[1]);
}
```

The error that the compiler gives is:

```
foobar_borrow2.rs:35:28: 35:36 error: cannot move out of `(*bar.a)[]` because it is borrowed
foobar_borrow2.rs:35     replace(&mut bar.a[0], bar.a[1]);
                                                ^~~~~~~~
foobar_borrow2.rs:35:13: 35:26 note: borrow of `(*bar.a)[]` occurs here
foobar_borrow2.rs:35     replace(&mut bar.a[0], bar.a[1]);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand what this means. This seems similar to the previous case, which worked. Why does adding the the `Bar` field to `Quux` cause it to fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand now, but first I think it's worthwhile to simplify. Let's change `Quux` to:

```
struct Quux {
        x: ~bool,
}
```

This causes the same error. Recall that `Foo.a` is a unique vector of `Baz`'s. `Baz` has copy semantics because it is a struct whose fields all have copy semantics (namely, a single `int` field). So passing `foo.a[1]` into the second parameter of `replace` causes its value to be copied.

On the other hand, `Bar.a` is a unique vector of `Quux`'s. `Quux` has move semantics because its sole field is an owned pointer to a boolean. So when we pass `bar.a[1]` to `replace`, it attempts to move ownership of the vector `bar.a` to `replace`. But we can't do that, because (apparently?) taking the mutable borrow of `bar.a[0]` in the first parameter of `replace` caused the entire vector to be borrowed already.

We can see this last fact about vectors in this simple example:

```
let mut x = ~[1, 5, 9];
let y = &mut x[0];
let z = &x[1]; //error: cannot borrow (*x)[] as immutable because it is already borrowed as mutable
```

In my original example, `Quux` has move semantics because it has a `Bar` field, and `Bar` has move semantics because it has a vector as one of its fields. So the same principles are in play.

Answer (score 0):

Here replace function <del>takes the ownership of the</del>  borrows `bar` when the compiler reaches the first use of bar, which is `bar.a[0]` in :

`replace(&mut bar.a[0], bar.a[1]);`

After that point, until the function is completed, the compiler prevents any further use of `bar`. Unfortunately this prevents the second argument to the function to be accepted because it is *taken* at the moment.

An alternative approach would be copying the content of `bar.a[1]` into a new variable and sending this new variable as the second argument to `replace()`:

```
let a1 = bar.a[1].clone();
replace(&mut bar.a[0], a1);
```

This copies the value in bar.a[1] to a new variable.

This would require bar and its contents to implement the trait `std::clone::Clone`. For this example adding `#[deriving(Clone]` to Bar and Quuz will work.

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Quux {
    x: bool,
    y: Bar,
}  

#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Bar {
    a: ~[Quux],
}
```

Comment: Why does the replace function take ownership of bar after the first parameter, but not of foo? Isn't the same thing happening with foo?